# Persistence context between stateless EJBs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a method (say method A) where I'm saving an entity to db; this method is inside EJB One. Within method A, after merging the entity, I call another method (say method B) which needs to work on data saved in method A. Method B is inside EJB Two.
Both EJBs are Stateless and in the same ear, so in EJB One I use the local interface of EJB Two.
Both have:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "emDevices")
    private EntityManager em;
```

When method B reads data from DB cannot find the new data saved previously in method A. 
I tried to use the @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS) without any success. 
Does anyone knows why method B cannot see data saved by method A even if they use the same persistence context?

I use hibernate 4.0.0 and weblogic 12.1.3 (J2EE6)

Comment: This should give you a decent idea of how transactions work with beans http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html

Comment: When you say "after merging" are you actually calling merge(). Merge and persist would probably do the same in this context, but in my experience a lot of developers don't know how to use merge correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you inject EJB Two in EJB One. If you have no TransactionAttribute set on EJB One, the default is REQUIRED, which will start a transaction, if not already one has been started. A transaction is needed to be able to persist data. Then if you inject EJB Two in EJB One and call a Method of EJB Two, the transaction is propagated. All should be OK. You are right, that the persistence context is shared. So you **should** be able to read, what has been written before, if it is really the same transaction.
A) What do you mean with *see data*? I think you use `em.find`? Then, it is OK; if you mean a query, it would be clear that the query would not return the data because it is still in the persistence context; the data will be commited at the end of transaction.

So what can be wrong, if it is not the point mentioned in A)?

- I would check, if it is really the same persistence context by printing out its instance in both methods; it should be the same address.
- Is it really the same transaction?
- Does your code really do, what you have described? In my point of view, it should work. So there may be a hidden difference?

If my answer does not help enough, please post a little bit more of your code; we could probably help bether then.

Comment: I completely agree with this analysis.

Comment: Also it wold work in the exact same way in you use Spring in a Java SE application. I actually prefer using spring instead of the EJBs (except in some rare occasions were I need stateful session beans).